# Integrating keycloak with angular 4

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to use keycloak with angular 4 for user management. I went through documentation but was left clueless about where to start. I am new to angular and keycloak. So, can anyone provide me with good documentation or help me with it by providing example?

I have run `npm install keycloak-js@latest --save` and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

1.Once you installed Keycloak,login to Keycloak and Configure your Client in KeyCloak server.

2.You can use Angular 4's , HttpClient to call the keycloaks admin api and service api(SPI).

I have found below resource which gives detailed explanation about integration.

[Integrating Keycloak with an Angular 4 Web Application](https://symbiotics.co.za/integrating-keycloak-with-an-angular-4-web-application/)